# Meaning of iperf TCP bandwidth of 24 Gbps on a Gigabit ethernet controller

Tags: tcp, bandwidth, ethernet, nic, iperf

I am using ubuntu and have a JMC250 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller.

I used iperf with TCP on localhost and it gave me a bandwidth of 24.2 Gbps. What is the meaning of this bandwidth? I did this test on localhost assuming it will come out to be somewhat close to the hardware limit, but it goes way over it.

iperf output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  4] local 127.0.1.1 port 5001 connected with 127.0.0.1 port 41954
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec  28.2 GBytes  24.2 Gbits/sec
```

Comment: "1000Gbps" is a typo. The JMC250 is a Gigabit adapter.

Comment: Oh! My bad. Then it maximum speed is 1 Gbps, right? How come iperf shows me 24.2 Gbps?!
I'll edit the question.

Comment: Yep, the maximum bandwidth of that adapter (on compatible networks) is 1 Gbps. You'd said that you were testing localhost loopback, which bypasses the adapter hardware. That value, 24 Gbps, probably reflects your memory bandwidth.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought loopback tests were used to test the network adapters (like ping), so those packets must go through the NIC and then back (bypassing wouldn't let people test NIC on local machine). But I guess ping is different somehow?

Comment: Your NIC never sees traffic addressed for localhost - that includes pings. It *does* pass through your machine's TCP/IP stack, which may be where your confusion comes in.

Comment: Now I am confused. Let me ask you precise questions:
1. If NIC is not working at all, can you know using ping?
(meaning do ping packets even reach NIC)
2. Are you saying that packet is sent and stuff on it is done till data link layer, but then it comes back (never touches the NIC?)

Comment: I just disabled all of the adapters on my machine (ok, not on this one, on the laptop sitting next to me). Then I did `ping localhost`. I got replies - pretty quickly, too :)

Comment: 1. You'd have to ping an IP address reachable via a route associated with the adapter you want to test. 2. (same as 1., really) Packets will flow to the adapter set up to handle the IP address that packet is addressed to.

Comment: Hmm. Great, got to know an interesting thing today. Thanks a lot!
Can you post a comment as an answer? I can accept it then, I cant accept a comment as an answer. :)

Comment: Sure; good reminder. Give me a min.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data addressed to localhost never leaves the TCP/IP stack on your machine. It's sent to the loopback adapter instead. The [loopback adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Virtual_Loopback_Interface_.28TCP.2FIP.29) is a virtual adapter - any traffic sent its way is sent right back to the caller, inside the stack. Your NIC never sees it.

It's not clear how real the 24.2 Gbps value is - you can see crazy values when you test with small enough datasets. To the extent that it's real, it may reflect your machine's memory bandwidth.

If you want to test the performance of your physical network adapter, or the network it's connected to, you'll need to interact with a host on your network, on a route that adapter is set to handle. If you have only one active physical adapter, that means any other host on your network.

Comment: Thanks.
iperf says it transferred 28.2GBytes, and also I know that my memory bandwidth is ~4 GBps, so your explanation sounds about right.

Comment: No problem. You probably meant to say 28.2Gbits, not Gbytes, which would make the math work out.

Comment: I am not sure about the math, but iperf say GB, not Gb. I edited the question to include the output, I am not able to format it in comments.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. It's 28.2 GB transferred over 10 seconds, resulting in a measured 24.2 Gb/s. That math works.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. :)